# Login to Firebase using phone returns null pointer

Tags: java, android, firebase, nullpointerexception, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to follow the tutorial from Firebase to allow users to login using their phone number. I've watched a tutorial video. All my code looks correct, but when I try it on my test device I receive a null pointer error.

```
 at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(Unknown Source)
    at studios.p9p.chatomatic.chat_o_matic.PhoneLogin.CheckPhoneNumber(PhoneLogin.java:92)
    at studios.p9p.chatomatic.chat_o_matic.PhoneLogin.access$000(PhoneLogin.java:29)
    at studios.p9p.chatomatic.chat_o_matic.PhoneLogin$1.onClick(PhoneLogin.java:52)
```

My code for the phone login is as follows:

```
private EditText et_check_phone_number;
private EditText et_verify_code;
private Button btn_phone;
private Button btn_verify;
private String getPhoneNumber, getVerifactionCode;
private String mVerificationId = "";
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseDatabase db;
private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mcallBacks;
private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
private ProgressDialog mloading;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_login); 

  mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    initVariables();
    btn_phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckPhoneNumber();
        }
    });

    btn_verify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            VerifyPhoneNumber();
        }
    });
}


private void initVariables() {
    et_check_phone_number = findViewById(R.id.et_phonenumber);
    et_verify_code = findViewById(R.id.etvarifaction);
    btn_phone = findViewById(R.id.btn_phone_login);
    btn_verify = findViewById(R.id.btn_phone_verify);
    mloading = new ProgressDialog(this);
}

private void CheckPhoneNumber() {
    getPhoneNumber = et_check_phone_number.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(getPhoneNumber))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Phone Number Field Cant Be Empty...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else{

                mloading.setTitle("Checking Your Phone Number");
                mloading.setMessage("It Gonna Take A Second...");
                mloading.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                mloading.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                mloading.show();

                PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                        getPhoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
                        60,                 // Timeout duration
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                        this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                        mcallBacks);
            }
    }

    mcallBacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

            Toast.makeText(PhoneLogin.this, "Wrong Or Invalid Phone Number...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            btn_phone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            et_check_phone_number.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            et_verify_code.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            btn_verify.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid Request " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                               PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
            // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
            mVerificationId = verificationId;
            mResendToken = token;
            Toast.makeText(PhoneLogin.this, "Code Sent Please Check Your SMS...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            btn_phone.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            et_check_phone_number.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            et_verify_code.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btn_verify.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    };
}




private void VerifyPhoneNumber() {
    getVerifactionCode = et_verify_code.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(getVerifactionCode)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter The Code Sent To Your SMS...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        mloading.setTitle("Checking Your Verification code ");
        mloading.setMessage("Ill Be Back In A Jiffy...");
        mloading.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mloading.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        mloading.show();
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId, getVerifactionCode);
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
    }

}
private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                     mloading.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(PhoneLogin.this, "Login Successful...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent phoneloginIntent  =new Intent (getBaseContext(),Home_Screen.class);
                        phoneloginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(phoneloginIntent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        String mesage = task.getException().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(PhoneLogin.this, "Error: " + mesage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

The "+44" I added trying to see if I was entering the wrong phone number. I tried it by adding the +44 manually into the edit text of the app first and that gave the same error.

### Edit

So I've removed the line inside the Auth provider that asked if the number was larger than 9 digits as it wasn't working. Also I ran a log to see if it capturing the phone number correctly.

```
Log.i("Verify_Phone_Number",getPhoneNumber);
 2019-07-16 14:15:30.585 32055-32055/studios.p9p.chatomatic.chat_o_matic I/Verify_Phone_Number: +447******100 and it returns correctly
```

### Edit 2

So on further testing if I click btn_phone before entering the phone number it works correctly, but if I simply add the phone number to the edit test first then press thebtn_phone it crashes with the above message in logcat.

Comment: Please post full activity code.

Comment: the only thing ive not posted is the variables?

Comment: Can't understand you're code properly please post full activity so we can understand

Comment: ive just edited the post to add full activity code

Comment: do u need xml as well?

Comment: Kind suggestion for the future: write consistent code. It'd be easier for all of us to help you. You cannot have one method starting with lowercase, another with uppercase. Or one variable mAuth, another mloader instead of mLoader. If text contains phone number, call it mPhoneNumber, or mUsersPhone, or something like that, not getVerificationCode. It is not verification code, it is phone number. Do not call anything with "get" unless it is method which gets something. Do not use verbs as a name anywhere but in method names. This is mess what you have here. Next time - help us to help you :)

Comment: Now, regarding your problem, since you put a lot of toasts as some kind of logging, can you share with us which toasts (in their order) are being shown when the bug/exception occurs?

Comment: Log you're phone number in specially with `"+44" + getPhoneNumber` in CheckPhoneNumber Function

Comment: Also, I would log/toast/or debug this line: "PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId, getVerifactionCode);" Can you do this and check what value do you have in getVerificationCode at that moment?

Comment: thanks @Ashish ill run a log now..

Comment: @markharrop so what's the output and please post full log

Comment: @Ashish i have removed the if statement and +44 as it wasnt working. ive also added the log of getphonenumber String thanks

Comment: can i post that as answer for you ?

Comment: The app still returns the same null pointer error

Comment: ill will totaly rewrite the code for this section and return to you once ive finished

Comment: @Ashish could you check my edit please pal? ive been testing and found that if i click the check phone number button first before entering the actual phone number then press it again it works.. but if i simply enter the phone number then press the button it crashes wtf?

Comment: Please Check my answer @markharrop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the way i solved this problem was to move the mcallbacks to the on create section of code. as shown below

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone__login);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    InitVariables();
    AddPhoneNumberButtons();

    mcallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Wrong Or Invalid Phone Number...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            AddPhoneNumberButtons();
            if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid Request " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                               PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
            // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
            verificationid = verificationId;
            mresendtoken = token;
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Code Sent Please Check Your SMS...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            AddVerifyButtons();

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

As per Firebase Docs you have to pass the Number with Country Code :

E.g.

```
phone number = +919090909090
```

See Following Picture :

[image]

As you can see even testing number needs country code with them.

When your app crashes it means Firebase `PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber()` not getting the number with country code.

You can try this following code before passing to if condition :

```
if (et_check_phone_number.getText().toString().startsWith("+44"){
    getPhoneNumber = et_check_phone_number.getText().toString();
}else{
    getPhoneNumber = "+44"+et_check_phone_number.getText().toString();
}
```

Above Code will check whether user put prefix of your country code or not.

Comment: @markharrop it's not in Tutorial but you have to check everything before include and Thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: ok finally figured it out. it was because i had the mcallbacks method in the same method as CheckPhoneNumber().. Moved it to after get contentView and it works great. i will post the answer underneath